# É possível enviar tags JSX do NodeJs(backend) para o ReactJs?

Tags: node.js, react, jsx

Preciso enviar um dado ao frontend, mas preciso que ele já esteja com determina tag em volta dele, por exemplo...

**dado backend:**
Nome: Gabriel

**preciso que chegue ao front dessa maneira:**

```
<div>Gabriel</div>
```

Comment: porque chegar um `html` pronto no seu front, já é de conhecimento o `React` faz isso para você? porque quer assim? complicar ou falta de conhecimento?

Comment: Por que não enviar pro front apenas a string "Gabriel" e no React encapsular dentro do elemento desejado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim totalmente possível! no backend você pode trabalhar com json e enviar os dados assim:

**no node temos uma variavel escrita com o nome header:**

```
const header = "<div><p>meu menu</p></div>"
```

A unica coisa que precisamos fazer é devolver para o frontend essa variavel:

**Algo nesse sentido:**

```
return res.json({header})
```

**e no frontend temos que usar no react um famoso carinha: (dangerouslySetInnerHTML), famoso por ser considerado perigoso rs mas se souber usar, não tem problema**

```
function createMarkup() {
  // aqui você faz a request para o node e atribui ele a variavel header
  const {header} = request.get('header');
  return {__html: header};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

link da documentação do [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)